# How to save an image to a file received from an iOS App with PHP encoded as Hex?

Tags: php, ios, png

My webserver is receiving an PNG image file from an iOS App via POST. 
I need to save this PNG to a file on the harddisk with PHP.

The POST-Data I receive looks like this:

&image=<89504e47 0d0a1a0a 0000000d 49484452...

As you can see I receive the image as HEX-data. I tried to save the image to disk but the resulting file won't open. All applications say that the PNG is corrupted.

The data I am receiving seems to be fine because if I simply put the POST Data from my webserver logfile inside a file with my HEX-Editor on my Mac the PNG will work.

My PHP Code:

```
$image = $_POST['image']);
$image = pack("H*", $image);
$filename = "image.png";
$f = fopen($filename,'wb');
fwrite($f, $image);
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$_FILE[]` method to send and retrieve your PNG image on iOS. Checkout this tutorial that explains how to generate the form and send it to your PHP service, it is quite straightforward :

http://iphone.zcentric.com/2008/08/29/post-a-uiimage-to-the-web/

Comment: +1 Send it as a file and you won't have to do anything fancy at the PHP end, just move your received file out of the temporary directory to wherever you'd like it stored.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have any control over the app because it is not developed by me.

Comment: what if you feed the imagecreatefromstream function of gd and write it to disk after that? cf. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Comment: example of implementation :
<?php
$src = "http://www.varuste.net/tiedostot/l_ylabanneri.jpg";
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($src));
?>

Answer (score 0):

My approach was the right one.

The reason my PHP code did not work was because the HEX-Data String provided by the iOS app 
was somehow formatted and therefore included spaces and "<" and ">" characters.

After removing them everything works.